# jQuery how to remove # from url

Tags: javascript, jquery

My url generates like this: only shows in ie9

```
http://myurl.com/#/categories/posts
```

how do I remove # from url and make it like `http://myurl.com/categories/posts` on rest of my pages? thanks.

can i use like this? how can I detect # cause front page has no #.

```
if ($.browser.msie  && parseInt($.browser.version, 10) === 9 && window.location.href.indexOf("#")) 
    {
        document.location.href = String( document.location.href ).replace( /#/, "" );
    }
```

to remove #/ used `.replace( /#\//, "" );` as mentioned Kevin B

Comment: Are you adding that for purposes of maintaining a history? You're going to need to provide a bit more background on your configuration.

Comment: Yes, also where do you want to remove it from? In my answer I assumed the address bar, Jones in his assumed all links in the page, it's not quite clear.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It's not really a JQuery job - use normal Javascript for this.

```
document.location.href = String( document.location.href ).replace( /#/, "" );
```

**EDIT**
Adding @Kevin B's answer for completeness

```
document.location.href = String( document.location.href ).replace( "#/", "" );
```

Comment: Mind if I ask, why the String constructor?

Comment: Legacy - I don't have old browsers at hand but I remember them complaining about document.location.href not being a string. Could be something veeery old like IE5.

Comment: I tought it would be something like that :), good to know (I suppose)

Comment: actually it replaces like this: http://myurl.com//categories/posts how can I remove that extra '/'

Comment: @Mercury `/#/` becomes `/#\//` or `/\/#/`

Answer (score 5):

Just add 'return false' for anchor tag's click event.

```
$("#selectorname").click(function(){
    if ($.browser.msie  && parseInt($.browser.version, 10) === 9 && window.location.href.indexOf("#")) 
    {
        document.location.href = String( document.location.href ).replace( /#/, "" );
    }
    return false; /* This prevents url from # */
});
```

or else

```
<a href="#" onclick='return false'>Hey click me, I'm # free</a>
```

or just make it simple

```
$("#selectorname").click(function(e){
   /* some statements */
   e.preventDefault();
});
```

This prevents the default action not to be triggered. Detailed info [here](http://api.jquery.com/event.preventdefault/)

Answer (score 2):

```
$("a").attr("href",$("a").attr("href").replace(/#/, ""));
```

Answer (score 0):

`<a href="#" onclick="return false">Hey click me, I'm # free</a>` does the work. I used this to hide # during Bootstrap dynamic tab switch. Thanks

```
<ul class="nav nav-tabs">
                            <li class="active"><a data-toggle="tab" href="#i-ab" onclick="return false">ab</a></li>
                            <li><a data-toggle="tab" href="#i-cd" onclick="return false">cd</a></li>
                            <li><a data-toggle="tab" href="#i-ef" onclick="return false">ef</a></li>
                        </ul>
```