# Popups via # link, how to remove # in the url, on closing?

Tags: javascript, html

I have several popups that I open by for example `http://example.tk/#example`, to close them I use:

```
<a href="#">Close</a>
```

Which closes the popup but it keeps the `#` symbol, obviously, is there some way I can close it and remove the `#` symbol?

I googled and found this:

```
<a href="javascript:void(0)">Close</a>
```

I've tried `javascript:`, `javascript:;` also.

But that does not work for me and I have JavaScript enabled.

Comment: Why have an href attribute at all? It's not needed if you've added an onclick event to close the popup

Comment: @Krii — It makes the element focusable so that you can "click" it without needing a mouse. That's pretty important for accessibility. (That isn't the best solution to the problem though).

Comment: This question appears to be what you need. Essentially, add an onclick handler that removes the # sign by modifying the `document.location.href`. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10036158/jquery-how-to-remove-from-url

Answer (score 3):

You have bound a JavaScript function to run when the link is clicked. You want that functionality to take place instead of following the link. So prevent the default behavior of the link.

```
document.querySelector("a").addEventListener("click", function (event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    open_popup();
});
```

… then the # will never be added to the URL in the first place.

---

Once you have done that, you can remember that [JavaScript can fail for many reasons](http://kryogenix.org/code/browser/everyonehasjs.html) and change the URL so that instead of pointing to the top of the page (`#`), it points to a useful separate page which serves the same purpose as the popup. See [Unobtrusive JavaScript](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unobtrusive_JavaScript) for further reading on the subject.

Answer (score -1):

Simply leaving the `href` empty, `href=""`, worked.